# Understanding "not" on booleans

Tags: c, boolean, c99, boolean-logic

My question seems simple, but I've been perplexed about it:

```
bool myBool = TRUE;
if (myBool) printf("1 myBool = true\n");
    else printf("1 myBool = false\n");
myBool = !myBool;
if (myBool) printf("2 myBool = true\n");
    else printf("2 myBool = false\n");

printf("%d\n", TRUE);
printf("%d\n", FALSE);
```

All of that outputs:

```
1 myBool = true;
2 myBool = false;
1
0
```

I understand why that is outputs. My question is how can a `!1` equal `false`? Because in C and C++, the `if` checks for a nonzero value. And the last time I checked:

```
TRUE = 0x00000001
FALSE = 0x00000000
```

therefore:

```
!TRUE = !0x00000001 = 0xfffffffd != 0
```

---

EDIT: I guess this confusion stemmed from my period of learning x86 assembly where a `not eax, eax` would perform a *bit-wise* not on `eax` (The equivalent of `eax = ~eax` in C).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are confusing logical NOT and bitwise complement.  The `!` operator returns 0 if the input is nonzero and 1 otherwise.  The `~` operator flips the bits of the input.  This means that `!0 = 1` and `!1 = 0`, which is not true when using `~`.

Also, remember that `if` statements check for whether the value is zero or nonzero.  Consequently, even if the value of the boolean was `0xFFFFFFFE`, it would still evaluate to `true` in an if statement.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

To complement the other answers, the specification states (C99 §6.5.3.3/5):

> The result of the logical negation operator `!`is `0` if the value of its operand compares
>   unequal to `0`, `1` if the value of its operand compares equal to `0`.
>
> The result has type `int`.
>
> The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.

Answer (score 2):

`!` is a *logical* `not` operator, so any non-zero input produces a result of 0, and a 0 input produces a result of 1.

The result you're thinking of would be from using a bit-wise not, as in `~true`.